# Losing faith in Allah and Islam , HELP?

Tags: islamic-basis

Assalamu Aleikum. I am 13 years old and I really need HELP.I was close to Allah swt and I wanted to know him more and know my religion more, So I saw Dr. Zakir Naik videos which is very helpful and I loved to see this videos, like any other video you can see 'Related videos', so I watched videos about athiest becomes muslim,... and then I saw muslim converts to christianity, I wondered how can a muslim leave the true religion and convert into other religion, so I saw these videos , and I thought what if there is no Allah or Islam is not the real religion? I didn't tell anyone about it , I just thought for a moment and then I said Astghfirullah and A'oozu billah. HOW CAN I THINK THAT ALLAH ISN'T TRUE ?! I had a struggle then because whenever I hear the name christianity-christ-christine-church-even america (cause the number of christians is more than the number of muslims), I freak out and then I also think of these stuff. I'm reading Quran and I always say zikr and pray 5 times and fast ... I love Allah and I repented to him after I thought of that but these thoughts are still chasing me , Am i getting sins when thinking bad ? I'm so afraid that If i die right now , Allah will say that I will certainly go to hell because of my thoughts, What should i do ??? Will these thoughts go by itself and I should just wait and read Quran and make duaa? I don't want to go to hell, I want to go to paradise and meet Allah but these thoughts are chasing me, when I pray I don't pray from my heart because when I pray I think that I didn't said that, I didn't wash my face 3 times when I was performing wudu, I'm in two troubles , shaytaan whistles in salah and my thoughts of Allah, I think that when I pray zuhr or any salah I pray it 5 TIMES, 25 PRAYERS A DAY FOR 5 PRAYERS, whenever I think of Allah in Salah in khushoo' , I forget what I'm saying during my prayer, Al hamdullilaah these days I'm focusing in my prayers but I don't think of Allah during all my prayers because I lose focusing on what I'm saying
-Does that mean that my prayers aren't accepted because I'm not thinking of Allah cause I'm trying to focus and stay away from the whistles of shaytaan ?
-Am I having sins because of my thoughts in Allah though I know that it isn't true and even when I'm trying to turn people to Islam and believing in Allah cause I know deep inside how Allah swt is merciful ?

Comment: Do not watch those videos which are not reliable and In Sha Allah praying 5 time with Zikr would help you out.

Comment: Please take the time to make your post clear and legible; as written, this is  unfocussed and just hard to read and risks deletion. I would strongly suggest you check out the advice in our help centre on "[How do I ask a good question?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" to better understand the sorts of posts we encourage here.

Comment: You should do an in depth study of science.. That will make your belief in a creator more stronger. However, it will also make you raise other questions... such as questioning the policies of God... but, that's another issue... One think is certain though... you will believe in a creator once you do an in depth study of the universe.

Answer (score 2):

You're too much young to freak out.
Everything will be ok sooner or later.
I don't remember very well but I have saw a haddith long ago about losing faith, and Muhammad saws said that it's normal to us to have our faith increasing and decreasing day by day, and your faith today means nothing about your faith tomorrow.

Pray, study and live your life.
Everything will be ok.
Insha'Allah.

If you doubt about the existence of a God, start to study science, you will find that it's impossible such complex universe without a creator.
Or just look at the stars. Look how they shine and think about the universe. You will understand when you do it.

Salam.